# commutative diagram with Yoneda pairing, Weil pairing and edge morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Why does the following diagram commute?$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    H^0(X,\mathscr{A})  \times \mathrm{Ext}^2_X(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}) @>>>  H^2(X,\mu_{\ell^n}) \\ @VVV   @| \\
    H^1(X,\mathscr{A}[\ell^n]) \times H^1(X,\mathscr{E}xt_X^1(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}))  @>>> H^2(X,\mu_{\ell^n}).
\end{CD}
($\mathscr{A}/X$ is an Abelian scheme.)
The vertical homomorphism $\delta$ on the left is induced by the Kummer sequence
$$
    0 \to \mathscr{A}[\ell^n] \to \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{A} \to 0.
$$

The upper row is the Yoneda pairing.

The lower row is induced by the Weil pairing
$$
    \mathscr{A}[\ell^n] \times \mathscr{A}^\vee[\ell^n] \to \mu_{\ell^n}
$$
using $\mathscr{E}xt^1(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}) = \mathscr{H}om(\mathscr{A}[\ell^n],\mu_{\ell^n}) = \mathscr{A}^\vee[\ell^n]$ by the long exact Ext sequence for the Kummer sequence
$0 \to \mathscr{A}[\ell^n] \to \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{A} \to 0$:
$$
    0 = \mathscr{H}om_X(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}) \to \mathscr{H}om_X(\mathscr{A}[\ell^n],\mu_{\ell^n}) \to \mathscr{E}xt^1_X(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}) \stackrel{0}{\to} \mathscr{E}xt^1_X(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}),
$$
the latter transition map being $0$ since $\ell^n$ kills $\mu_{\ell^n}$. (Edit 2: Or, better,
$$
    0 = \mathscr{H}om_X(\mathscr{A},\mathbf{G}_m) \to \mathscr{E}xt^1_X(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}) \to \mathscr{E}xt^1_X(\mathscr{A},\mathbf{G}_m) \stackrel{\ell^n}{\to} \mathscr{E}xt^1_X(\mathscr{A},\mathbf{G}_m)
$$
and using $\mathscr{E}xt^1_X(\mathscr{A},\mathbf{G}_m) = \mathscr{A}^\vee$, as pointed out in the comments.)

Finally, for the middle vertical arrow:  The local-to-global Ext spectral sequence $H^p(X,\mathscr{E}xt_X^q(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n})) \Rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}_X^{p+q}(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n})$ gives us an injection (an edge morphism, see also [Natural morphism appearing in Grothendieck spectral sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28827/natural-morphism-appearing-in-grothendieck-spectral-sequence/159656#159656))
$$
    H^1(X,\mathscr{E}xt_X^1(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n})) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Ext}_X^2(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n})
$$
since $\mathscr{H}om_X(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}) = 0$.

Edit: Differently stated, why does
\begin{CD}
 \mathrm{Ext}^2_X(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n}) @>>>  \mathrm{Hom}(H^0(X,\mathscr{A}), H^2(X,\mu_{\ell^n})) \\
 @AAA  @A\delta^*AA  \\
 H^1(X,\mathscr{E}xt_X^1(\mathscr{A},\mu_{\ell^n})) @>>> \mathrm{Hom}(H^1(X,\mathscr{A}[\ell^n]), H^2(X,\mu_{\ell^n}))
\end{CD}
commute? (the left vertical arrow a edge map of the spectral sequence and the right vertical arrow $\delta^*$ with $\delta$ the connecting map of the Kummer sequence)

Comment: If you write everything out with cocycles (eg wrt a fppf hypercovering), then you should be able to decide whether it is true or not by a computation. Did you try? Also, a reference for a good number of commutative diagrams involving the dual abelian scheme A^t, identifying it with Ext^1(A, G_m), and identifying A^t[l] with Hom(A[l], G_m), double duality, etc is Oort's LNM 15.

Comment: The description of the bottom row is "cheating" a bit, since in reality one should say we use the isomorphism $\mathscr{Ext}^1(A,\mu_{\ell^n}) \simeq \mathscr{Ext}^1(A,\mathbf{G}_m)[\ell^n] = A^{\vee}[\ell^n]$ and the pairing between torsion-levels in $A$ and $A^{\vee}$. (Edit: answer_bot wrote a related comment at the same time.)

Comment: The diagrams appear all jumbled to me. Do other people have the same issue?

Comment: I fixed the second diagram, hopefully. Dear @Timo Keller, please check it is as you intended. Regarding the first diagram in the question, I cannot tell what you were trying to write. Please fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to fix the first diagram accordingly, but on the left, there should by two vertical arrows pointing down and up, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Show that (in the lower diagram) $H^1(X,\mathscr{H}om(\mathscr{A}[\ell^n],\mu_{\ell^n}))$ embeds via the first edge homomorphism into $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathscr{A}[\ell^n],\mu_{\ell^n})$ (by the local-to-global Ext spectral sequence) and that the lower horizontal and left vertical arrows factor through this.
2. Now both paths map $e = (0 \to \mu_{\ell^n} \to \mathscr{F} \to \mathscr{A}[\ell^n] \to 0) \in \mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathscr{A}[\ell^n],\mu_{\ell^n})$ to $H^0(X,\mathscr{A}) \stackrel{\delta_\mathrm{Kummer}}{\to} H^1(X,\mathscr{A}[\ell^n]) \stackrel{\delta_e}{\to} H^2(X,\mu_{\ell^n})$.